# Passing characters such as # and ++ in query string?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I create a hyperlink that when clicks generates a url like so:

http://somesite?MyTag=C++

And I read it into a text box like so:

`Me.txtTags.Text = CType(Request.QueryString("Tag"), String)`

But the result of this is that the textbox txtTags will only contain C and doesnt have the ++.
I tried http://somesite?MyTag=C# and the # is missing as well.
But if I look at the address bar these values are there....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `UrlEncode` when you building url and `UrlDecode` when you are trying to read url params

```
MyURL = "http://www.contoso.com/articles.aspx?title=" & Server.UrlEncode("C#")
```

Answer (score 5):

try

```
Me.txtTags.Text = Server.UrlDecode(Request.QueryString("MyTag"))
```

Comment: What module should I import to get Server.UrlDecode ?

Answer (score 4):

`#` is used as the anchor tag, so it's not a legal query param. It represents the end of the query string and segues into the beginning of the anchor string. I just ran into this problem myself yesterday :)

`+` is generally used to encode spaces in URLs, so it won't show up in a query string either.

Answer (score 1):

'#' can't be used since it is used for HTML anchors. Don't know the exact answer for the + though

Answer (score 1):

You should Encode the string when you are generating that link using `Server.UrlEncode`, here is an example:

```
MyHyperLink.NavigateUrl = "http://www.mysite.com/default.aspx?mytag=" & Server.UrlEncode("C++")
```

And when you are trying to process it in default.aspx, you should decode it using `Server.URLDecode`, here is an example:

```
Me.txtTags.Text = Server.UrlDecode(Request.QueryString("mytag")) 'This will show "C++" without quotes in txtTags textbox.
```

You may want to read more about `Server.UrlEncode` [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zttxte6w.aspx#Y0) and about `Server.UrlDecode` [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6196h3wt.aspx#Y0).

Answer (score 0):

Here is a list of Special Characters for Query String

http://permadi.com/tutorial/urlEncoding/